# Finite State Machine / Workflow for Marionette

Tags: marionette

I have seen many FSM implementation and workflow implementation in javascript but i couldn't figure out something that exist for Marionette framework or something that goes hand in hand with marionette framework?

I am afraid Marionette may not need such implementation or it may be overkill....given the case it may already doing it in one of their components.

If i need to implement an FSM, do i need look beyond marionette or i can do some simple tweak in one of their components and get the work done.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest FSM is an object which stores state and emits a signal upon state changes. If this is what you need you can use a Backbone Model for it. If you need a little more complexity here's a few Backbone specific ones:

- [backbone.statemachine](https://github.com/sebpiq/backbone.statemachine)
- [backbone.fsm](https://github.com/fragphace/backbone-fsm)